# Passing escape characters to grep -e command via Python subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, regex, bash, grep, subprocess

I want to call this command from Python using subprocess: `grep -e '^commit [a-z0-9]{40}'`

When I call this command directly in terminal it doesn't work unless I escape the braces with backslashes like: `grep -e '^commit [a-z0-9]\{40\}'`

When I try to pass this string, with the escape characters, to the command using Popen in python it doesn't work.  Here is what I have tried:

```
grepCommand = ['grep', '-e', "'^commit [a-z0-9]\\{{{0}\\}}'".format("40")]
grepCommand = ['grep', '-e', "'^commit [a-z0-9]\\\\{{{0}\\\\}}'".format("40")]
grepCommand = ['grep', '-e', "^commit [a-z0-9]\\{{{0}\\}}".format("40")]
grepCommand = ['grep', '-e', "^commit [a-z0-9]\\\\{{{0}\\\\}}".format("40")]
```

How can I properly format this string in python, so that I can pass it to grep via Popen?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you use grep from within your python script, rather than use a native python solution?

Comment: `r"'^commit [a-z0-9]{40}'"`

Comment: You need to insert a backslash before the `{` and `}` because that's the format for basic regexen. You might have intended to use the `-E` option instead of `-e`; `-E` is for extended regular expressions, while `-e` just indicates that the next argument is a pattern (useful if the pattern starts with a `-` or if there are more than one pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list already is a parameter seperation, so extra quoting with `'` is not necessary:

```
grepCommand = ['grep', '-e', r"^commit [a-z0-9]\{{{0}\}}".format("40")]
```

Comment: There is in errant single quote in this answer, but otherwise it worked!